# Uniquely identify elements which are inside android Compound View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

**The Problem:** How to uniquely identify elements which are inside android Compound View?

**Background:** 
In my application I used Compound View. Because  It has two TextFields, one image and one seek bar in each row. The layout is working fine.

So in the layout there are two separate seek bars. I need to get the value of them in my activity.

I can identify each row separately because they have id. But the items inside the row repeat in each row.

My problem is 
**how can I identify each seek bar uniquely?**

row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/colunm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="40sp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dip"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </merge>
```

screen_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <com.example.test.view.Compound
            android:id="@+id/vol_Row1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:column_summary="TEST SUMMARY I"
            custom:column_title="Test TITLE 1"
            custom:image_Icon="@drawable/ic_action1" />

        <com.example.test.view.Compound
            android:id="@+id/vol_Row2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:column_summary="TEST SUMMARY 2"
            custom:column_title="Test TITLE 2"
            custom:image_Icon="@drawable/ic_action2" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

row_layout class

```
    public Compound(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a=context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.Options, 0, 0);
        String titleText=a.getString(R.styleable.Options_title);
        String summaryText=a.getString(R.styleable.Options_summary);
        int icon=a.getInt(R.styleable.Options_image_Icon,0);

        a.recycle();

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,this,true);

        imageView=getChildAt(0);
        imageView.setImageResource(icon);

        title=getChildAt(1)
        title.setText(titleText);

        summary=getChildAt(2)
        summary.setText(summaryText);

    }
}
```

Comment: did you create class for row_layout?

Comment: yes I did. Layout is working fine.But I need to identify each element separately.Do you have any idea?

Comment: first you need give id to your SeekBar in your Row_layout... then in the row's class create getter to get the seek bar value. its help you? or you want sample code?

Comment: But the seekbar in row_layout repeat in each row. Also I need to access them outside this row's class. Is that possible to do? Could you please give me some sample code?

Comment: you can please post your row_layout class so i can edit it for you, thats be much easer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in this way. In compound view I gave unique ids to each element. Then in test code I could access them uniquely like this,

```
private View inflaterView;
    LayoutInflater i=(LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflaterView=i.inflate(R.layout.screen_layout, null);
        seekBar=(SeekBar) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.vol_Row1).findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, add an ID to the seekbar in your XML layout file.

```
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seek"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Second, in your code, use `findViewById` on the instance of the `Compound` view of which you want to obtain the reference to it's seek bar:

```
Coumpund c1 = (Compound)findViewById(R.id.vol_Row1);
Coumpund c2 = (Compound)findViewById(R.id.vol_Row2);

SeekBar sb1 = (SeekBar)c1.findViewById(seek); // Gives you the SeekBar of c1
SeekBar sb2 = (SeekBar)c2.findViewById(seek); // Gives you the SeekBar of c2
```

Comment: I did it some other way and I will update my answer later. BTW thanks for the help.